# Symbology on joined variables not showing up on map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, attribute-joins, mapping, visualisation

I am trying to add a certain styling to points I have on the map. I have set a Rule-based styling with a range added based on a different variable. Both variables were added to the point DB from a different CSV through the join function in QGIS.

Unfortunately though after I have set the rules the points do not show up on the map (not only the rules don't show up, the points disappear altogether). Does anyone know why this happens and how to solve it?

Comment: Well, did the join actually happen?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Erik the join did happen, nothing wrong on that side

Comment: Then please provide example data, as well as your rules.